# Is there a difference between the urlencode method in python 2 and in python 3

Tags: python-3.x, python-2.7, urllib, urlencode, ringcentral

I am working with ringCentral's API and trying to get auth token using password mechanism using python 3. Earlier I did it with python 2 and it is still working fine. I used urllib.urlencode() method to URL encode the request parameters,as required in the API doc. Equivalent of that method in python 3 is urllib.parse.urlencode(), but i'm getting below error when executing in python 3.

```
{"error": "invalid_request", "errors": [{"errorCode": "OAU-156", "message": 
"Basic authentication header is missing or malformed"}], "error_description": 
"Basic authentication header is missing or malformed"}
```

I even printed the resulting string from urlencode method in both cases and it is the same. I don't understand what's the problem here? Any insights? I can't find any info with that error code either.

Python 3 code:

```
    import urllib.parse
    import json
    import requests
    basic="%s:%s" % ("<my cllient id>","<my cllient secret>")
    auth_header = {
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        "Accept": "application/json",
        "Authorization": "Basic "+ str(base64.b64encode(basic.encode()))
    }
    body = urllib.parse.urlencode({
        'grant_type': 'password',
        'username': "<my number>",
        'password': "<my password>"
    })
    auth_request=requests.request("POST","https://platform.devtest.ringcentral.com/restapi/oauth/token",headers=auth_header,data=body)
    print(json.dumps(auth_request.json()))
```

Python 2 code(working):

```
    import urllib
    import json
    import requests
    basic="%s:%s" % ("<my cllient id>","<my cllient secret>")
    auth_header = {
        "Content-Type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
        "Accept": "application/json",
        "Authorization": "Basic "+ str(base64.b64encode(basic.encode()))
    }
    body = urllib.urlencode({
        'grant_type': 'password',
        'username': "<my number>",
        'password': "<my password>"
    })
    auth_request=requests.request("POST","https://platform.devtest.ringcentral.com/restapi/oauth/token",headers=auth_header,data=body)
    print(json.dumps(auth_request.json()))
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to put your code here so that we can troubleshoot the issue.
In the meantime could you please check RingCentral using Python 2 and 3, you can learn step by step to access RingCentral services using Python native API here: 
https://ringcentral-tutorials.github.io/call-ringcentral-apis-native-python-demo/?distinctId=171e1c5b614e8-078e90c97b438a-1d346655-fa000-171e1c5b615fa#0

You can find how it is accessing status code, defining and handling tokens and handling Authorization